# Xamarin.Forms throws exception on Navigation.RemovePage if Page is not On top

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

My navigation looks like: **MainPage->Page1->Page2**.
When I navigate back to `MainPage` from `Page1` within the `OnAppearing` method of `MainPage`, I execute the code piece below.

Normally `backbutton` should remove the page from `NavigationStack`, but XF does not always handle this. I make sure that `NavigationStack` and Memory is cleaned. This works perfectly fine in Android.

```cs
var existingpages = Navigation.NavigationStack.Where(p => !(p is MainPage)).ToList();
if (existingpages?.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var page in existingpages)
    {
        page.BindingContext = null;
        Navigation.RemovePage(page);
    }
}
```

But on iOS I getting and unhandled exception:

```
NavigationRenderer.OnPopViewAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page page, System.Boolean animated)
System.AggregateException: Popped page does not appear on top of current navigation stack, please file a bug.
```

I looked into the Xamarin.Forms [NavigationRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/caab66bcf9614aca0c0805d560a34e176d196e17/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/NavigationRenderer.cs) source code for iOS and it is by design. If a page is not the top page, it is not possible to remove from the `NavigationStack`.

Is it a bug in XF or design by Apple? I cannot find any information regarding that in Apples docs. Any experience here?

```cs
protected virtual async Task<bool> OnPopViewAsync(Page page, bool animated)
{
  if (_ignorePopCall)
    return true;

  var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(page);
  if (renderer == null || renderer.ViewController == null)
    return false;

  if (page != ((ParentingViewController)TopViewController).Child)
    throw new NotSupportedException("Popped page does not appear on top of current navigation stack, please file a bug.");

  var task = GetAppearedOrDisappearedTask(page);

  UIViewController poppedViewController;
  _ignorePopCall = true;
  poppedViewController = base.PopViewController(animated);

  var actuallyRemoved = poppedViewController == null ? true : !await task;
  _ignorePopCall = false;

  poppedViewController?.Dispose();

  UpdateToolBarVisible();
  return actuallyRemoved;
}
```

Comment: did you file a bug as directed?

Comment: To work around it, Reverse the order in which you remove pages. That is, iterate through the collection backwards. Or use a call that pops top page, until none are left.